# Programming for a Roland EGX 350

Tags: c#, c++, plot

I am about to make a program in C++ or C# that can control a Roland EGX 350 engraving machine. Its use is for engraving signs, where the text is automatically fetched from an ordering system.

I have already installed this Windows driver http://dg4.roland.co.jp/en/upgrade/program/25d_winxp32.exe and the machine is connected through USB.

I have, however, not been able to find any information about, which data format the engraving machine supports. Should I send HPGL commands? G-Code? Or something entirely else?

TIA

/ Carsten

Comment: What does the support say? The [brochure](http://www.rolanddg.com/PDF/egx-350.pdf) talks about **rml-1**

Comment: But how is this outputted from a C++ og C# program to the machine through the USB port?

Comment: On Linux I would "just" send it to stdout and then pipe it to /dev/usb-something. But I am unsure how it is done on Windows

Comment: Typically, USB drivers do install some COM-emulation-drivers. These appear to the system as old-style serial ports (but much faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - found a driver from Roland, that makes the machine behave like a plotter. Now I can just send black/white graphics paths from normal Windows printing.

Thanks anyway Henno for the effort. :-)

/ Carsten